# Saving site as a template breaks Gantt view of list

Tags: web-part, list, gantt-view

I am in the process of creating a project management system, in which there is a Gantt chart of all the tasks, displayed as a view of a particular list. I am attempting to save the site as a template so that a copy of the site can be used for each project created, therefore creating a project management 'site' for each project.

To do this I save the template and include all the data (so it includes the lists etc). When I then create a site from the template, the embedded list web parts work perfectly, but in Gantt view I get the following error:

> "List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does
>   not exist. it may have been deleted by another user."

To clear things up a little, this is in a 'task centre' page which displays the gantt view, tasks assigned to the logged in user, overdue tasks, and all tasks. All these sections use the same list and are added as individual web parts with filters. After the site creation from template, all work perfectly except the gantt view, which displays the aforementioned error.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue in my O365 instance. I've contacted microsoft support. I'll let you know what I hear. There may be nothing we can do, except delete the webpart and applying the view again. (which is what i've been doing.)

Comment: I too am facing this exact same issue on a SharePoint 2013 standard on premise installation. I have a raised a ticket with MS, and they haven't yet been able to resolve this issue. Anyone else here has faced this issue, and any solutions?